# Printing the value as it is in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, database, csv, mybatis

I need to store exact values whatever I get from a database into a csv. When I try to store 0 it is being stored as 0.0 in the csv.Although it is insignificant the client wants the exact same value to be stored in the database.

```
 double c = Double.valueOf("0");
```

I get 0.0 in the CSV.
One more constraint is that  I should not be using any String operations to get the exact values.
Is there any way where I can get the exact values ?

Comment: ``int i = Integer.valueOf("0")``?

Comment: No this is not the only values.I get other double values also like 15.3 so that would be affected.

Comment: What type of value you are storing in database like integer or double? If you are using double then it will add decimal point for the same. Either you can convert it to Integer or you can change data-type for this value.  Let me know if you still facing any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply do this: `d % 1 == 0` to see if some double d is whole.

if yes you do `Integer.valueOf(number)`

else store it as it is

Comment: This seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way where I can get the exact values ?

Not with a `double`. Like decimal (for example `1 / 3`), there are numbers that can't be represented without loss of precision in floating point (which is why [`0.1+0.2` is `0.30000000000000004`](http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2999)). That being said `BigDecinal` has [`stripTrailingZeros()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You are using Double here I think you have to use Long ,Double will stored as 0.0 its natural behavior